# Fluentd crashes on startup

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, fluentd

I am trying to follow this guide http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/free-alternative-to-splunk-by-fluentd on how to set up fluentd, elasticsearch, and kibana.  I am setting it up on Ubuntu 14.04.  When I try to start td-agent, it crashes right away.
Here is the section of the log regarding the crash:

```
2015-10-01 21:47:21 +0000 [info]: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224
2015-10-01 21:47:21 +0000 [info]: listening dRuby uri="druby://127.0.0.1:24230" object="Engine"
2015-10-01 21:47:21 +0000 [info]: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224
2015-10-01 21:47:21 +0000 [error]: unexpected error error_class=Errno::EADDRINUSE error=#<Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 24224>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue.  In the guide, it says to modify the td-agent.conf as follows:

```
<source>
  type syslog
  port 42185
  tag syslog
</source>

<source>
  type forward
</source>

<match syslog.**>
  type elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  flush_interval 10s # for testing
</match>
```

but the `<source>type forward</source>` section was already in the config file